# what is binary in binary json (BSON)?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongodb-query, bson

Why binary word is being used for BSON,when it stores data in the format like

```
A document such as { "hello": "world" } will be stored as:

Bson:
  \x16\x00\x00\x00               // total document size
  \x02                           // 0x02 = type String
  hello\x00                      // field name
  \x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00      // field value (size of value, value, null terminator)
  \x00                           // 0x00 = type EOO ('end of object')
```

for this format also we need interpretor to parse and convert it to machine instruction and

In what way it is compressing the actual JSON data and make fast interpretation?

Comment: *"...we need interpretor to parse and convert it to machine instruction.."* - No that's an entirely different thing. These are not "machine instructions" but just a "format of bytes" in order to store data. JSON-like does not mean it was ever JSON at any point. In all reality it's just a "marketing name" for what is "just another packed data structure".

Comment: Don't forget that `{ "hello": "world" }` only ever looked like that to JavaScript. To Java or C# or Go it looked like something completely different and native to that language. BSON is the "universal translation" from any of those forms. But with "types", which text based things like JSON does not have.

Comment: I mean to say does the term binary hold any significance to BSON, and what property of BSON make it fast.

Answer (score 0):

It's an analogy semantics for binary data types. BSON binaries has a array of bytes  representing a internal subtype from 0 to 127.

For example: the byte 0000 0000 1000 represents the hexa "\x08" which means the type boolean in BSON specificiation.

The driver will be in charge encoding and decoding formats UTF-8 to BSON and Storage Engines such as WiredTiger in MongoDB will responsible for serializing and deserializing at data in BSON format.

Comment: but what makes the parsing of that data more fast?

Comment: Accessing bson for WiredTiger is more suitable and fast becasue it's by design  even considering there is a trade off converting json to bson. I made some tests with in memory and wt are pretty similars about time in my environment.